# UICollectionView inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I've noticed iOS it's very mean when using `UICollectionView` inside an `UITableViewCell`. What I'm trying to achieve, it's to have a Collection of Images (`UICollectionView` approach) inside a `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to mimic Facebook post style, I think, they have an `UITableView`, with custom cells and so on, but **here's** the Problem...

I've managed to put the `UICollectionView` inside an `UITableViewCell`, and It worked correctly and perfectly, no problem, everything showing fine, it's clickable and so on. BUT, I tried to refactor my code, extracting the *`UICollectionViewDataSource`* & *`UICollectionViewDelegate`* into separate files for Reusing them and having less code on the `Main View Controller`, it is here, when my **Nightmare** begun, I don't know why if I'm using separate files iOS Cycles the configuration of the Cells. For example:

```
-(void)configureCell:(UICollectionViewCell*)customCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

The above method it's being called on two parts of the process:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 NSString *identifier = [self retrieveIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];
 UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
 [self configureCell:myCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
 [cell setNeedsLayout];
 [cell layoutIfNeeded];
 [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
 [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
 CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize].height;
 return height;
}
```

The above method it's invoked to calculate the Row Height using AutoLayout I read this on a Post here at **StackOverFlow** ( don't remember the post :( )

After the height it's being calculated and so on, another method calls the "`configureCell`" method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *rowName = [self retrieveIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];
    PostDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:rowName forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //PreCondition
    if([rowName isEqualToString:@"LoadingRow"]){
        return cell;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath withImages:YES];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

When the debugger starts, the method *`configureCell:atIndexPath:`* it's being called over and over and over again. this is the second time this happens. Does that mean that I can't "separate" the `DataSource`? Or ***IT IS IMPOSSIBLE*** to add an `UICollectionView` inside an `UITableViewCell`. Or, Am I using a bad approach? Is there a way to do this?

I'm very confused on this...

Thank you guys!

Comment: The same problem I am having.. Didn't get solution so far.

Comment: It's not nice to go through an entire cell configuration to just determine row height.

Comment: Don't know how to calculate height :/ all the examples I saw recommended to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this for a very long time, spent hours redesigning the Layouts, etc, etc.
And I finally got the Solution:

This is the Header File of my Cell

```
@interface MyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

 -(void)setImages:(NSArray*)images;
@end
```

And Here's the Magic beyond all of this the Implementation File (m)

```
@interface MyCustomTableViewCell() <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;
@end
@implementation MyCustomTableViewCell
-(void)setImages:(NSArray*)images{
 _imageArray = images;
 [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
 [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
 [_collectionView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource Methods
...
...
...
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate Methods
...
...
...
@end
```

Using the Above approach made the CollectionView show and also show it's content. I also wanted to add an action to the CollectionView, for example, showing **MWPhotoBrowser** when an Image it's being clicked, I added a method to the Header file of the cell:

```
-(void)setViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController;
```

Seted It on the Implementation file and called the **MWPhotoBrowser** on the Delegate Methods. I know it's really weird, because it forces me, to use a Cell for showing the DataSource & Delegate. When I should be able to recycle my DataSource & Delegate at other points, weird. But It worked!!

Thank you, Guys!