# Obj-C- Datasource for UICollectionView inside of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a TableView (self.tableView) inside of a ViewController (DashboardViewController). Inside of this tableview, I have a custom cell that contains a UICollectionView.

Everything works fine, however in order to populate the UICollectionView, I'm currently calling data inside my UITableViewCell, which I don't want to do, as every time I scroll up and down, data is called.

Is it possible to make the UICollectionView's datasource an NSMutableArray inside DashboardViewController, instead of having to populate the NSMutableArray inside the UITableViewCell in which it is sitting?

My setup right now:

**UITableViewCell.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *clientsWeek;
```

**UITableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    
     [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ClientCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ClientCollectionViewCell"];

     [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
     [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    
    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams1 setValue:@"cdata" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        
        
        self.clientsWeek = [responseObject mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"The people are here %@", self.clientsWeek);
        

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UICollectionView inside an UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999400/uicollectionview-inside-an-uitableviewcell)

Comment: No @koen. It appears as though the accepted answer does not address that issue?

Comment: Cells are reused, so you need to populate the embedded collection view every time the cell is either created or reused. We have no idea what data you are retrieving in your HTTP Request, but you might want to develop a "data manager" that would "cache" the information so you don't have to make that remote call every time.

Comment: It is possible to avoid cell reuse. For your TableView just create and populate each cell once and keep a reference. In `cellForRowAt` from TableView, return the same cell (depending on `indexPath`). This way, your UICollectionView inside the UITableViewCell will not keep on being reloaded when you scroll. However, I think this approach is only suitable if your TableView has fixed content.

Answer (score 0):

Under the premise that the **CellReuseIdentifier** is set correctly.

Of course, you can choose to get all the data in `DashboardViewController`, including the datasource of `UICollectionView`. Here you need to combine the data. The data source of the tableview must be an array, so the data source of UICollectionView can be placed in the array. Like this

```
[
  {
   "UITableViewCellData":{},
   "UICollectionViewData":{}
  },
...
]
```

Of course you can also use data model objects to replace.

Then you need to expose a method for receiving the data source to the cell, in which you can refresh your UICollectionView.

**UITableViewCell.h**

```
- (void)cellWithDataSource:(NSDictionary *)dataSource;
```

**UITableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)cellWithDataSource:(NSDictionary *)dataSource{
  NSDictionary *tableViewDataSource = dataSource[@"UITableViewCellData"];
  NSDictionary *collectionViewDataSource = dataSource[@"UICollectionViewData"];
  ...
}
```

`DashboardViewController` passes data to cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];
    // first obtains the datasource of each cell, and passes it to each cell
    [cell cellWithDataSource:datasource];
    return cell;
}
```